# How to create a new admin settings page in php

Tags: php

I'm a new in PHP developing. I have to create wed admin page. If admin enters the login page, all the users details will be displayed. If the user enters the page, only his details will be displayed. Please help me out of this

Comment: admin page is separate from user page . you need to set pointer in DB in user table lets say is_admin. after this you can query accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It is very basic in PHP or in any other language.
When you develop login management system then You have to first manage session.
You have to store ID or username(which is uniquely identify user) in session.
In the basis of this session ID you can display data of particular user.
and when you logout then destroy this session ID.